# get torch (flash) state to toggle it in android M

Tags: android, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to implement toggle torch functionality. So that the camera does not get captured and crash - as in Lollipop - I am attempting it with `setTorchMode` in API 23.
I have a code implementation to turn on or off the torch; however, I don't know how to check the current state of the flash.

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
try {
    String[] cameras = manager.getCameraIdList();
    for (int i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameras[i]);
        boolean flashAvailable = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
        if (flashAvailable) {
            boolean flashState = getFlashState(); //MISSING METHOD
            manager.setTorchMode(cameras[i], !flashState);

        }

    }

} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, how do I implement `getFlashState` without using the old camera API? And is it possible to do it without capturing the camera?

Answer (score 9):

You can try using

```
CameraManager.TorchCallback torchCallback = new TorchCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTorchModeUnavailable(String cameraId) {
        super.onTorchModeUnavailable(cameraId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTorchModeChanged(String cameraId, boolean enabled) {
        super.onTorchModeChanged(cameraId, enabled);
        flashState = enabled;
    }
};
```

and register callback with

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    manager.registerTorchCallback(torchCallback, null);// (callback, handler)
```

when you want to turn on / off the flash uses

```
manager.setTorchMode(cameras[i], !flashState);
```

Remember unregister callback...

Answer (score 0):

Go through the [link1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#FLASH_STATE) and [link2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AE_MODE) you will get the solution.

`android.flash.mode` will help you to get the FLASH mode.